# "Cannot Open Page" Error when doing Facebook single sign on in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have setup a view in my appcelerator titanium app to be nearly identical to the one in the kitchen sink demo for facebook login.  I want to use single sign on for IOS:

```
//LoginView Component Constructor
function LoginView() {
    //create object instance, a parasitic subclass of Observable
    var self = Ti.UI.createView();
        // APP ID BELOW IS CHANGED FOR DEMO PURPOSES
    Titanium.Facebook.appid = "111111111111111";
    Titanium.Facebook.permissions = ['email', 'publish_actions'];
        // ENABLE SINGLE SIGN ON
    Titanium.Facebook.forceDialogAuth = false;

    self.add(Titanium.Facebook.createLoginButton({
        style:Ti.Facebook.BUTTON_STYLE_WIDE,
        bottom:30
    }));


    return self;
}

module.exports = LoginView;
```

When clicking the login button, it successfully opens the facebook login dialog in safari and I login.  Then when it tries to take me back to the app, I get the error:

> **Cannot Open the Page** Safari cannot open the page because the address
>   is invalid

Very similar code works correctly in the kitchen sink app, and also disabling single sign on makes logging in through facebook work correctly in my app.

All I have for the settings in the facebook app is:
Facebook Login - Enabled

Am I missing anything from the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

In my facebook app settings (on developers.facebook.com), I set the bundle Id to the same id as my app in Appcelerator.

[Based on the q & a:](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/137876/how-to-use-facebook-single-sign-on)

Copied Info.plist from build/iphone/ into the root of the application.

Added the xml element fb111111111111111 below under app to Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.mycompany.app</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>app</string>
            <string>fb111111111111111</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Where 111111111111111 is changed to the id of the app